# What does ECLK rate mean?

Tags: cpu, clock-speed, bit-rate

I'm reading a spec doc on some CPU and I didn't get what does this mean:

> The CPU core requires only a single clock input at the ECLK rate

- What does ECLK abbreviation stand for?
- What does ECLK rate mean in a technical sense?

Comment: External CLocK - a signal that provides the clock for the CPU from an external source.

Comment: First guess: external clock. Then again it could mean a lot, post a link to the document you read it in.

Comment: External Clock makes sense. If anyone interested in writing an answer to this question we can close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External Clock - ECLK
It's rate would be defined in Hz and specified by the maker of the chip.